# SQL Server routine of inserting multiple rows after checking if they don't exist - how can i improve my perfomance?

Tags: c#, sql-server, bulkinsert

I have an sql server 2008 db table that holds links to articles.
My app routine is that every ~1-10 seconds i get a list of 10-100 new articles that contain a url,
and what i need to do is check every article's url and if it doesn't exist on the db i will add it.

How i do it know :
first thing - i made a unique index for the url so no matter what - i won't have the same url more than once (of course i normalize the url e.g cut it's 'http://www.' prefix etc before i insert it).

the 'InsertArticles' method is something like this:

1. Open a transaction
2. for each link - check (using the transaction) if its url exists in the db
3. for each unexisting link - add the link (of course,using the same transaction)
4. execute and close the transaction + handle transaction/general exceptions

the thing is - most of the time it works very fast (0.05-0.2 secs) for about 10-20 or so links..
but sometimes it gets much slower - it can even take 50 secs to call this method with 50 articles.

So 2 questions here -

1. is what I do ok ? should i use transactions for this kind of a job?
2. what alternatives do i have ? maybe insert if not exists ?

i was also thinking - why not just 'brute insert' the new articles to the db - meaning, i will try to insert all the input url's to the db and I will let sql server throw an exception for those urls that already exist there..

Maybe using a stored proceude to do all of this can enhance perfomance ?

anyway any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://www.sergeyv.com/blog/archive/2010/09/10/sql-server-upsert-equivalent.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the MERGE-statement to combine the SELECT and INSERT into one statement:

```sql
-- Table "links" with column "url"
MERGE links AS L
USING (SELECT url FROM links WHERE url = @url) AS I (url)
ON (L.url = I.url)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (url) VALUES (@url)
```